# Updating events in Fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I have a problem editing objects in Fullcalendar. When I click 'Save' in a form I can edit propperly the events of the Fullcalendar in a server side, but it doesn't work in the client side. The events don't change immediately, I need to upload the page to see the changes in the event(object). I've been reading the documentation of fullcalendar and I've found this $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event); I've wrote it but it doesn't work.

This is the javascript code

```
     function drawControl(controls) {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            editable: true,
            aspectRatio: 1,
            contentHeight: 500,
            scrollTime: '24:00:00',
            minTime: '01:00:00',
            maxTime: '24:00:00',
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            header:{left:"prev,next,today",
            center:"title",
            right:"month, agendaWeek, agendaDay"},


            events: allControls(controls),

            eventRender: function(event, element) {

                var bloodLevel=event.title

                if(bloodLevel >= 180) {
                    element.css('background-color', 'red');
                }
                else if(bloodLevel < 70) {
                    element.css('background-color', 'yellow');
                }
            },
            eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                    x=calEvent.id;
                $('#modalTitle').html(calEvent.title);
                $('#control_day_edit').val(moment(calEvent.start._i).format("DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm A/PM"));
                $('#control_level').val(calEvent.title.toString());
                    console.log(calEvent)
                    console.log(calEvent.title)
                    console.log(calEvent.start._i)
                    console.log(calEvent.id)
                $('#eventUrl').attr('href',"/users/:user_id/controls/calEvent.id/edit");
                $('#fullCalModal').modal();
                y=calEvent;

            }
})
}
 });

document.getElementById('button_edit').addEventListener("click", editControl);

 function editControl(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     console.log(y);
     console.log(x);
     var controlEdited = {
         "level": document.getElementById('control_level').value,
         "day": document.getElementById('control_day_edit').value,
         "period": document.getElementById('control_period').value,
         "id": x
    }
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', y);
    $.post("/editControls", JSON.stringify(controlEdited));

    console.log(controlEdited)

};




 $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
            $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker();
        })
```

I think the key could be in the place where I should add

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', y);
```

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: this doesn't answer your issue with eventUpdate, but what i've done is set in the 'event:' setting, cache to false. so when I update an event, i simply reload the calendar to have the change reflected.

Comment: How can I do that?? I mean where I should put the cache: false ???

Comment: in your event set.. check docs for the event source; http://fullcalendar.io/docs1/event_data/events_json_feed/#caching

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work. I set cache to false but it only changes if I reload the page, but that already worked. What I need is the event to change without reloading page.Thank you anyway.